# Creating own FILE* pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, filesystems

I had just a look at the stdio.h where I could find the FILE structure 
definition:

```
typedef struct  {
   int             level;      /* fill/empty level of buffer */
   unsigned        flags;      /* File status flags          */
   char            fd;         /* File descriptor            */
   unsigned char   hold;       /* Ungetc char if no buffer   */
   int             bsize;      /* Buffer size                */
   unsigned char   *buffer;    /* Data transfer buffer       */
   unsigned char   *curp;      /* Current active pointer     */
   unsigned        istemp;     /* Temporary file indicator   */
   short           token;      /* Used for validity checking */
} FILE;
```

Now, I am wondering if I could create myself (not using fopen) a valid FILE pointer
to a stream which I could use then in subsequent calls for fread or fwrite? It is
more a theoretical question so please do not wonder why I wanna know that ;)

Moreover, is it correct that stdio does not provide a routine to delete a file? In
this case I need OS calls, don't I?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

No, you shouldn't even try to that as it's not portable. The C99 spec says that you even shouldn't try to copy an existing `FILE` object as it's address ‘may be significant’.

And stdio provides `remove()` function to remove a file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! On my ported stdio lib there is no remove() function defined.

Comment: That's strange because AFAICS `remove()` is even defined in ANSI C spec.

Comment: Indeed it is. James01, your library is not standard-compliant.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you know your library inside out: One component of every FILE structure is the "file descriptor", usually an integer. This is how the *kernel* identifies the stream.

Your library cannot access the file system itself, it has to rely on system calls to the kernel. These system calls don't use the FILE structure to identify a stream, but merely the "file descriptor" from it.

On a POSIX system, you get that file descriptor from the open(2) call.

It *is* possible to get that file descriptor, and initialize the FILE structure yourself, if you know the library requirements well (and every library, even every library *version*, could vary widely in these requirements).

But then, you haven't done anything different than fopen() does for you - only fopen() is more comfortable.

For deleting a file, use remove().

Answer (score 1):

The content and meaning of FILE is undefined. Different compilers/libraries, and different versions of the same compiler/library can have completely different content, or even just subtle but breaking changes.

FILE is meant to be an opaque block of data that allows the different library functions to share state.

It is *not* designed to be broken apart and reused by user code.

OTOH there is nothing to stop you, other than the knowledge that any solution based on this will be fragile (at best).

Answer (score 1):

On BSD, you can use [`funopen` or `fropen`/`fwopen`](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man3/funopen.htm) to create a `FILE*` with custom callback functions for I/O.

On Linux, a similar function is [`fopencookie`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fopencookie.3.html).

Not that it's portable or recommended, but it's a way of creating valid `FILE` pointers without using `fopen`.

For file removal, there's `remove` and `unlink` pointed out by other answerers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your standard library implementation, it *may* be possible to create your own `FILE` structure and use it. However, this is completely unsupported, may or may not actually work as expected, and certainly won't be portable between different library implementations.

To delete a file, call `unlink()`, which (on my system) is in `<unistd.h>`.